# Getting a records position from an order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the position of a specific record in the context of an order call?

For example:

```
username = User.find(1)

User.all.order("created_at DESC").position_of(username)
```

Is there anything like this?

Comment: `each_with_index` might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421305/rails-display-chronological-order-of-number-of-records

Answer (score -1):

There is [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) method:

```
user = User.find(1)
index = User.order('created_at DESC').index(user)
```

Comment: The point is that User.order(created_at: :desc) is not an array. So you will get a "undefined method 'index' for #<User::ActiveRecord...".
User.order('created_at DESC').to_a.index(user) may work.